# ¿Qué función es mejor en términos de controlar excepciones y ser mas segura?

Tags: c#

Os escribo esta pregunta porque me ha surgido una duda. Tengo que leer un fichero de texto que puede ir separado por ***',' , ';' o ' |'***. Creando código me he encontrado con uno que ya había hecho y sería algo tal que así:

```
using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@lRutaFichero))
{
    while ((linea = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        cArticulo = cCantidad = "";
        if (linea.IndexOf("|") >= 0)
        {
            cArticulo = linea.Substring(0, linea.IndexOf("|"));
            cCantidad = linea.Substring(linea.IndexOf("|") + 1, linea.Length - linea.IndexOf("|"));
        }
        else
        {
            if (linea.Substring(0, 1) == ",")
            {
                linea = linea.Substring(1, linea.Length - 1);
            }
            if (linea.IndexOf(",") < 20)
            {
              cArticulo = linea.Substring(0, linea.IndexOf(","));
              cCantidad = linea.Substring(linea.IndexOf(",") + 1, linea.Length - linea.IndexOf(",") - 1);
            }
        }
        if (cArticulo != "")
        {
            NuevaLinea();
            LineaSeleccionada.CANTIDAD = decimal.Parse(cCantidad);
            LineaSeleccionada.CANTIDADCARACTER = cCantidad;
            LineaSeleccionada.CANTIDADORIGEN = cCantidad;
            ArticuloLeido = cArticulo;
        }
    }
file.Close();
}
```

Por otro lado el código que he creado antes de haber encontrado el anteriormente mostrado es este, a mi parecer es mas "leíble" pero no se que tanto de seguro es (a falta de hacer la distincion para los otros tipos de separadores):

```
var Lista = File.ReadAllLines(lRutaFichero).Select(x => new
                {
                    CBarras = x.Split(';')[0],
                    Cantidad = decimal.Parse(x.Split(';')[1])
                }).ToList();

                int ArticulosNoEncontrados = 0;
                string MensajeCuerpo = $"No se han encontrado los siguientes codigos de barras:{Environment.NewLine}";
                foreach (var item in Lista)
                {
                    MiniArticulo Articulo = (new ArticuloAplicacion()).ObtenerMiniArticuloPorCBarras(item.CBarras);
                    if (Articulo == null)
                    {
                        ArticulosNoEncontrados++;
                        MensajeCuerpo += item.CBarras + Environment.NewLine;
                        continue;
                    }
                    ProveedorDTO Proveedor = (new ProveedorAplicacion()).ObtenerProveedorConId(Articulo.IDPROVEEDORES ?? 0);
                    LineasArticulos.Add(new DocumentoLineaMultiPedidoDTO()
                    {
                        ORDEN = LineasArticulos.Count() + 1,
                        REFERENCIA = Articulo.REFERENCIA,
                        DESCRIPCION = Articulo.DESCRIPCION,
                        CODIGOPROVEEDOR = (Proveedor != null) ? Proveedor.CODIGO : "",
                        NOMBREPROVEEDOR = (Proveedor != null) ? Proveedor.NOMBRE : "",
                        CANTIDAD = item.Cantidad,
                        PRECIO = Articulo.UNIDADPRECIO,
                        TOTAL = Articulo.UNIDADPRECIO * item.Cantidad
                    });
                }

                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LineasArticulos));

                if (ArticulosNoEncontrados > 0)
                {
                    Mensajes msg = new Mensajes(EnumMensajesTitulo.INFORMACION, MensajeCuerpo, EnumMensajesBotones.ACEPTAR);
                    msg.ShowDialog();
                }
```

**PD**: Mencionar que ambas funciones están dentro de Try-catch

El codigo finalmente ha quedado dividido en dos funciones:

```
private void LecturaDeArticulo()      //Función Principal
private string ObtenerSeparadorArchivo(string ruta) //Función dentro de la principal
```

```
private void LeerArchivoPistolaAction()
        {
            try
            {
                string separator = ObtenerSeparadorArchivo(RutaFichero);

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(separator))
                {
                    Mensajes msg = new Mensajes(EnumMensajesTitulo.INFORMACION, "CarácterSeparadorNoControlado", EnumMensajesBotones.ACEPTAR);
                    msg.ShowDialog();
                    return;
                }

                var Lista = File.ReadAllLines(ruta).Select(x => new
                {
                    CBarras = x.Split(char.Parse(separator))[0],
                    Cantidad = decimal.Parse(x.Split(char.Parse(separator))[1])
                }).ToList();

                int ArticulosNoEncontrados = 0;
                string MensajeCuerpo = $"No se han encontrado los siguientes codigos de barras:{Environment.NewLine}";
                foreach (var item in Lista)
                {
                    MiniArticulo Articulo = (new ArticuloAplicacion()).ObtenerMiniArticuloPorCBarras(item.CBarras);
                    if (Articulo == null)
                    {
                        ArticulosNoEncontrados++;
                        MensajeCuerpo += item.CBarras + Environment.NewLine;
                        continue;
                    }
                    ProveedorDTO Proveedor = (new ProveedorAplicacion()).ObtenerProveedorConId(Articulo.IDPROVEEDORES ?? 0);
                    LineasArticulos.Add(new DocumentoLineaMultiPedidoDTO()
                    {
                        ORDEN = LineasArticulos.Count() + 1,
                        REFERENCIA = Articulo.REFERENCIA,
                        DESCRIPCION = Articulo.DESCRIPCION,
                        CODIGOPROVEEDOR = (Proveedor != null) ? Proveedor.CODIGO : "",
                        NOMBREPROVEEDOR = (Proveedor != null) ? Proveedor.NOMBRE : "",
                        CANTIDAD = item.Cantidad,
                        PRECIO = Articulo.UNIDADPRECIO,
                        TOTAL = Articulo.UNIDADPRECIO * item.Cantidad
                    });
                }

                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(LineasArticulos));

                if (ArticulosNoEncontrados > 0)
                {
                    Mensajes msg = new Mensajes(EnumMensajesTitulo.INFORMACION, MensajeCuerpo, EnumMensajesBotones.ACEPTAR);
                    msg.ShowDialog();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        private string ObtenerSeparadorArchivo(string ruta)
        {
            try
            {
                List<string> ListaSeparadores = new List<string>();
                ListaSeparadores.Add(",");
                ListaSeparadores.Add(";");
                ListaSeparadores.Add("|");
                string separator = "";

                string archivo = File.ReadAllText(ruta);

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(archivo))
                {
                    Mensajes msg = new Mensajes(EnumMensajesTitulo.INFORMACION, "NoSeHaPodidoAbrirElArchivo", EnumMensajesBotones.ACEPTAR);
                    msg.ShowDialog();
                    return string.Empty;
                }

                foreach (string item in ListaSeparadores)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(separator))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (archivo.Contains(item))
                    {
                        separator = item;
                    }
                }

                return separator;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: El Try y catch es la mejor opción para manejar excepciones, solo tienes que identificar en que partes necesitas controlar que el proceso siga o definitivamente se detenga.

Comment: Para que poner un try, que no hace nada? mejor que el programa falle.. si no sabes que hacer con un problema, mejor no lo agarres.. aparte de eso, no entiendo cual es tu pregunta...

Comment: Igual no me expliqué bien pero la idea es hacer un codigo simple para la lectura y que no tenga ningun fallo de seguridad en el sentido de que haya algun error no controlado en el sentido de no se hubiera controlado algun caracter especial dentro del archivo por ejemplo.

Igual con usando el try-Catch como dice @Marco Cantu Gea es suficiente